# Adding different type to return of Redux dispatched async actions

Tags: typescript, redux

I am writing some middleware to handle API interaction

Example:

```
type CommentResponse = Promise<{ comments: any[] }>
const getComments = createApiAction<CommentsResponse>('GET_COMMENTS', {
  callApi: (api) => api.getComments()
})
```

Here I'd like the typing of `getComment()` to be the actual action object which is easy enough.

But, I once I dispatch the action, I'd like the returned type to be the `CommentsResponse`, and not the action object itself

```
const action = getComments() \\ should be the action type
const result = store.dispatch(action) \\\ should be a promise and autocomplete 'result.comments' on the resolved value
```

But I am not sure how I can change the typings of Redux's `.dispatch` function like this

Any ideas?

Comment: where does `createApiAction` come from ?

Comment: It's part of the middleware im writing, it's basically just an action creator factory